# Filtering by array within ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I would like to filter my list of objects in the `ng-options` by those that match a certain condition within the object.

For example I have data like this:

```
{
        id:1,
        type:"Type A",
        name:"loc 1",
        items:[
            {id:1, name:"item 1"},
            {id:2, name:"item 2"},
            {id:3, name:"item 3"},
        ]
    },
```

My select looks like this

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="location as (location.name + ' ' + location.items.length + ' items') group by location.type for location in locations | filter:{items.length:filterBy.itemId}">
</select>
```

The example below works by filtering the list by the number of items in the array, but what I want to do is to filter the list by those that have a criteria such as all objects that have an item with id=1.

Here is a working fiddle with the above.

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/qyqgv6z0/)

What I would like/expect (in pseudo) something like:

```
ng-options="location as (location.name + ' ' + location.items.length + ' items') group by location.type for location in locations | filter:{items{id:filterBy.itemId}}"
```

Is it even possible?

**Update**: The fiddle above has been updated with the code in the answer from @Marcos Sandrini below in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck with ng-options, you always have the choice to do whatever you want with `options` tag in a ng-repeat, not the ideal case for everything, but it works just as well most of the time and it is much more readable and understandable, especially for more complex cases.

```
<option value="{{location.id}}">
   {{location.name + ' ' + location.items.length + ' items' | orderBy: 'location.type' | filter:IdFilter(location,idToFilter)}}
</option>
```

Just be sure you don't use ng-show and ng-hide with option tags, it won't work (use ng-if instead). The filter function goes below:

```
function IdFilter(location,idToFilter){
  var hasId = false;
  angular.foreach(location.items, function(l){
    if (l.id===idToFilter) hasId = true; 
  }
  return hasId;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that filters my list in any way?

Comment: I added that now. Check if this gives the result that you want.

Comment: I managed to get your code to work in my fiddle and have updated the fiddle with the working version if anyone wants it. The groupBy doesn't work and was throwing an error so I have left that out for the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by a function

```
this.filterFunction = function(item) {
      return item.itemId===1;
}
```

and so you would then just use

```
filter:filterFunction
```

Comment: I tried that but that only filters by the main object. So in my example it returns the location with the id=1. Not what I want.